# VBA - Copy and paste loop based on cell value containing date

Tags: vba, date, copy, paste

I'm working with a data extracted from a PDF in excel. I'm trying to create a macro that will check a date input in the "Guide" tab, and copy all lines data with a matching date from one sheet to another.

```
Sub Copy()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim myRow As Long
Dim myCopyRow As Long
Dim Data As Worksheet
Dim Form As Worksheet

Set Data = Sheets("PDF Data ")
Set Form = Sheets("Formula")

myCopyRow = 2


lastrow = Data.Cells(Data.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


With Data
    For myRow = 1 To lastrow
        If Data.Cells(myRow, "A") = Sheets("Guide").Cells(C3) Then
        Data.Cells(myCopyRow, "B") = Form.Cells(myRow, "A")

        myCopyRow = myCopyRow + 1
    End If
Next


End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

when debugging I get  the following:

"Runtime error '1004': Application-defined or object -defined error2"

for  line:

If Data.Cells(myRow, "A") = Sheets("Guide").Cells(C3) Then

The data I am trying to compare are dates. The user input date on the "Guide" is recognised and formatted by Excel as a short date, however, the date on Sheet1 is initially recognised as a string of text, since it is split using formula from a larger string. I initially thought this was the issue so tried reformatting with no luck.

I hoping someone could take a look and let me know if there is anything wrong with the above code, and confirm if both cells with both need to be recognised as dates? and can VBA convert them before checking?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `.Cells` method takes a row and column number, not a Range Reference

Answer (score 2):

For the VBA runtime error - If you want to check the value against the value in cell `C3`, use the `Range` method, instead of the `Cells` method:

`If Data.Cells(myRow, 1).value = Sheets("Guide").Range("C3").value Then`

For comparing dates, you can convert values into dates using `CDate`

`If CDate(Data.Cells(myRow, 1).value) = CDate(Sheets("Guide").Range("C3").value) Then`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Cells method then you need the following syntax:

```
Worksheets("Guide").Cells(3,"C")
```